# How to treat injured female pigeon?

Tags: medicines, birds, injury

5 days before, I had seen one pigeon was walking lame in my home's balcony. I could not understand what happened to her. I put her in big box. I have been treating her by giving Arnica-30 homeopathy medicine (5-5 pills morning and evening), and Arnica ointment. But no any effect. Any expert suggestion (for exact medicine) would be appreciated. Following are the few pictures of bird. This seems as big fleshy wart at right side of wing of bird.

[image: injured bird]
[image: Ointment]
[image: Bird]

Comment: Any animal that has an injury or changes its behavior very suddenly should always be examined by a vet. We don't know the cause or extend of this injury, so we cannot possibly tell you how to treat it correctly.